# Iterating over const T& in a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> >

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, unique-ptr

I have a class like this:

```
class RPNExpr
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Expr> > m_exprs;
};
```

Each element of m_exprs is heap-allocated by a builder function, should be readable by other classes, but is purely owned by RPNExpr and should be destructed when the RPNExpr goes out of scope.

It would be nice for readers of m_exprs to be able to get an iterator over const Expr&, i.e. an iterator which hides the fact that the vector is holding unique_ptrs. I would like this for the sake of consistency with other classes, which hold unique_ptrs to their data and return const T& to them.

The interface for this might look something like:

```
class RPNExpr
{
public:
    SomeIterator expr_begin();
    SomeIterator expr_end();
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Expr> > m_exprs;
};
```

Consumers should then be able to iterate over the Exprs by using standard iterator operators.

Is there a nice way to do this? Should I be writing a vector wrapper which abstracts over the pointers? Should I not be doing this at all and use something other than unique_ptrs in my vector?

Comment: Is `boost::ptr_vector` a suitable replacement?

Comment: @C.R. I guess I could use ptr_vector and manually delete all the Exprs in ~RPNExpr. I was hoping I'd be able to avoid using boost and keep my automatic deletion, but this seems like a good alternative if that is not possible, thanks.

Comment: I think that you could define you own iterator class that inherits from the default iterator and that returns a const T& whenever you dereference it.

Comment: @vratojr that might be possible, but I thought inheriting from vector<T>::iterator was bad practice as they are implementation-defined?

Comment: @TartanLlama: `boost::ptr_vector` assumes ownerships of all its member pointers so you need not and should not delete them in ~RPNExpr. And why are you hoping to avoid boost?

Comment: @TartanLlama: I think vratojr meant inherit from `std::iterator`, not `vector<T>::iterator`

Comment: @C.R. Ah, I hadn't clocked that from my brief look at the docs. I was hoping to avoid boost as this is for a project I envisioned to gain a better understanding of C++11 and LLVM, so a bit of wheel reinvention is not an issue; I'm not against boost in principle.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Paul is right, I meant std::iterator or,better, the proper derived class that suits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an iterator adaptor in boost that does just that:

```
#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>
...
using ExprIterator = boost::indirect_iterator<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Expr>>::iterator>;
ExprIterator expr_begin() { return std::begin(m_exprs); }
ExprIterator expr_end() { return std::end(m_exprs; }
```

Source: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely. You can even template that `using` typedef to have a generic `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`->`T&` iterator.